# Use 'case' over Signal.Address Action

Tags: elm

I have the following type Action:

```
type Action = ActionA A.SubAction | ActionB B.SubAction
```

where A and B two different types, each holding a SubAction type.

I want to implement a method using 'case' to perform an operation depending on the type of the address parameter.

```
view : Signal.Address Action -> Html
view address =
    case address of
        Signal.Address (ActionA action_a) ->
            ...
        Signal.Address (ActionB action_a) ->
            ...
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find pattern `Signal.Address`.
The qualifier `Signal` is not in scope.
```

Could someone help me see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to pull the `Action` out of the address parameter using a case statement. The [signature of `Address`](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/2.1.0/src/Signal.elm#l303-l304) is

```elm
type Address a =
    Address (a -> Task () ())
```

If your `view` function needs to know which action was last performed, you're probably better off adding a `lastAction : Action` field onto your `Model`, then setting it in `update`.